# Help with $\int_0^\infty x^me^{-ax^n}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, closed-form

I need the solution of the following integral $$\int_0^\infty x^me^{-ax^n}dx$$ where $a,n,m$ are all positive constants with $n\geq 2$. I have searched for it in the Gradshteyn but was unable to find a solution for this.

For $n=2$ I think we can use some thing used for normal distribution but for general values of $n$ I do not know how to solve it.

Comment: $x = y^{1/n}/a^{1/n}$ and it reduces to the Gamma function $\Gamma(s) = \int_0^\infty y^{s-1} e^{-y} dy$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One may perform the change of variable
$$
x=\frac{u^{1/n}}{a^{1/n}},\quad dx=\frac{u^{1/n-1}}{na^{1/n}}du,\quad ax^n=u,
$$ obtaining
$$
\int_0^\infty x^me^{-ax^n}dx=\frac{a^{\large -\frac{m+1}{n}}}{n}\int_0^\infty u^{(m+1)/n-1} e^{-u}du
$$ then, using the standard [integral representation of the gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function), one gets

> $$
> \int_0^\infty x^me^{-ax^n}dx=\frac{a^{\large -\frac{m+1}{n}} }{n}\Gamma\left(\frac{m+1}{n}\right).
> $$

Comment: what does this yellowish background means in your last equation? Does it signify something? I have seen this in many posts

Comment: @FrankMoses : it means "this is the answer" :D